# Invite friends to play games on Facebook

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I want to send request to play game with me to my Facebook friends. For this purpose, I have studied following Facebook sample application also read complete Facebook documentation from their site.

[Friend Smash Unity](https://github.com/fbsamples/friendsmash-unity)

To use this sample code, I have created application in Facebook account. Now at this stage I can able to send Facebook game request to friends and they receive it successfully but when they click on it, they didn't move to either Google Play Store or same installed application.

I think, I didn't specified play store link in Facebook account for this app also currently game is in development phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for this problem after reading following tutorial : [Android Games Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial)

Basically for my facebook application, I have not enabled **Single Sign On** and **Deep Linking** toggle buttons.

I have found following content on tutorial and get idea about my mistake.

> Ensure you enable both 'Facebook Login' and 'Deep Linking'. Enabling 'Facebook Login' ensures that when users click on a request, bookmark, or search result in the Facebook for Android app, it will attempt to open up the native Friend Smash app if it is installed (or take the user to Google Play to download the game if it isn't installed). Likewise, enabling 'Deep Linking' ensures the native Friend Smash app opens when a Feed story is clicked in the Facebook for Android app.

Now using notification, I can able to move on play sore or installed application. I hope this help to other members also.