# "This game is not available for your phone" Facebook Notification Error

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an app using Ionic / Cordova. I have set up the app in the Facebook Developer console and integrated login with Facebook through Google Firebase. I am currently trying to implement Facebook game invites.

I am using this code to send the invite:

```
temp.fb.showDialog({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'I challenge you to beat me in Pigs N Bulls!',
    max_recipients: 1,
    data: sGameID
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I am trying to test this by sending my friend an invite. The invite is sent, but when he goes to accept it, it tells him that the app is not available for his phone. (Which is hard to believe since the app is installed on his phone.)

[image]

He is listed in the console as an app tester, which should give him access.

Is there a setting that I have missed that will allow the Facebook app to open mine?

Comment: What solved the issue in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case where my app will not actually live on Facebook, (it is iOS and Android only) the solution seems to be enabling the "Single Sign On" option in the developer console under the platform.

Answer (score -1):

Enable both Single Sign On and Deep Linking and make sure that the Class Name points to an activity that has android:exported="true" set in the AndroidManifest (if that isn't set, you'll get a permission error and crash when you click the link). [Here's a better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840651/invite-friends-to-play-games-on-facebook)